# Size, referencing and dereferencing a dynamic array of structures

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code, I'm not able to figure out the referencing and dereferencing of array pointer containing an array of structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        typedef struct inputData_{
                char fname[64];
                size_t dsize;
                int nx1;
                int nx2;
                int nx3;
                int geom;
                int swap_endian;
                double *x1;
                double *x2;
                double *x3;
                long int offset;
        } inputData;

        int n = 10;
        inputData (*arr)[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(inputData));
        printf("inputData size: %d\n",sizeof(inputData));
        printf("arr size: %d\n",sizeof(arr));
        printf("*arr size: %d\n",sizeof(*arr));
        printf("arr[0] size: %d\n",sizeof(arr[0]));
        printf("**arr size: %d\n",sizeof(**arr));
        printf("*arr[8] size: %d\n",sizeof(*(arr[8]) ));
        (*arr[5]).nx1 = 10;
        (*arr+5)->nx1 = 20;
        return 0;
}
```

Following is the output:

```
inputData size: 128
arr size: 8
*arr size: 1280
arr[0] size: 1280
**arr size: 128
*arr[8] size: 128
```

`arr size: 8` is what I understand as it is a pointer.
What I find very confusing is that from the following lines,

```
(*arr[5]).nx1 = 10;
(*arr+5)->nx1 = 20;
```

it looks like elements of the dereferenced `*arr` looks like both a pointer to a structure and also a structure simultaneously. Any explanation of this would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` will return a `size_t` and must be printed using `%zu`. So all your `%d` are wrong.

For the the line

```
(*arr[5]).nx1 = 10;
```

the explanation is:

`arr` is a pointer to an array of structs.

So `arr[5]` is an array of structs.

Now remember that in most expressions an array is converted to a pointer to the first element. So when you do

```
*arr[5]
```

the `arr[5]` part is converted to a pointer to a struct. So the `*` dereference that pointer an leaves you with a struct. Consequently you can do:

```
(*arr[5]).nx1 = 10;
```

You can also notice that

```
(*arr[5]).nx1 = 10;
```

is the same as

```
arr[5][0].nx1 = 10;
```

Finally notice that

```
sizeof(arr[0])
```

is one of the few exception where an array is **not** converted to a pointer. Here it will be taken as an array  and that is the reason that `sizeof(arr[0])` will give 1280.

Now the second line:

```
(*arr+5)->nx1 = 20;
```

is kind of the same explanation. It's the same as

```
arr[0][5].nxl = 20;
```

In general it's worth to know that the pattern

```
TYPE (*arr)[COLUMNS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *arr);
```

is the C way of making dynamic 2D arrays.

So for the code:

```
TYPE (*arr_a)[COLUMNS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *arr);
TYPE arr_b[ROWS][COLUMS];
```

`arr_a` and `arr_b` can both be used as 2D arrays using the `arr_x[..][..]` syntax for access. The difference is that `arr_a` is allocated dynamic while `arr_b` is allocated automatic.